# Rails model with other model as instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I am building a Rails application that contains `Developer`s who have `Application`s. Both Developers and Applications are objects whose contents come from an external API. Thus, both of these models are hand-written and do not take advantage of ActiveModel, ActiveResource, etc.

I am trying to determine how to instantiate the Application object as an instance variable of the Developer object.

I have the following code within my `Developer.initialize()` function:

```
@apps = Array.new
data['applications'].each do |app|
  @apps << Application.new(app)
end
```

The code is fairly self explanatory. Both `developer.rb` (which is where Developer is defined) and `application.rb` (which is where Application is defined) lie in the `app/models` directory. My developers controller instantiates a Developer object by calling `Developer.new`.

The line of code within the do block produces the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Developer::Application
app/models/developer.rb:24:in `initialize'
app/controllers/developers_controller.rb:11:in `new'
app/controllers/developers_controller.rb:11:in `show'
```

So it looks like Rails is trying to instantiate a Developer::Application, whereas I want to instantiate the Application object defined in `application.rb` within the `app/models` directory. Is there some way for this to be done?

Comment: Your code isn't very Ruby-esque; that first segment could be: `@apps = data['applications'].map { |app| Application.new(app) }`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for pointing that out. I'm in the process of learning Ruby and Rails (& am most comfortable with C/C++) so I'm not always on top of the most efficient way of writing things in Ruby. Either way, the call to Application.new(app) gives me that error, though.

Comment: It's possible that 'Application' is a reserved namespace in Rails - Does the problem go away if you name the model something else?

Comment: In my code, its actually not called Application, I just simplified it for the sake of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to require the necessary files. In my case, from within the Developer class, I needed the following line: `require 'application.rb'` and everything worked fine.